# RxJava + Retrofit share() operator

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit, retrofit2, rx-java2

Peculiar rx scenario here:

Retrofit API:

```
interface MyApi {
  @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
  @POST("something")
  fun doSomething(@Body body: SomeRequestBody): Single<SomeResponse>
}
```

This API can be called from multiple places. So, I'd like to share it. My repository exposes this:

```
class Repository {

  private val observable: Observable<SomeResponse> by lazy {
    myApi.doSomething(SomeRequestBody())
        .toObservable()
        .share()
  }

  fun doSomething(): Completable {
    observable.flatMapCompletable { Completable.complete() }
  }
}
```

I'm testing this with the following:

```
// passes, as expected
@Test
fun `multiple api calls share`() {
  given(myApi.doSomething(any())).willReturn(Single.just(RESPONSE).delay(2, SECONDS))

  val test1 = repository.doSomething().test()
  val test2 = repository.doSomething().test()
  val test3 = repository.doSomething().test()

  test1.await(3, SECONDS)
  test2.await(3, SECONDS)
  test3.await(3, SECONDS)

  test1.assertNoErrors()
  test2.assertNoErrors()
  test3.assertNoErrors()

  test1.assertComplete()
  test2.assertComplete()
  test3.assertComplete()

  verify(myApi, times(1) /* for clarity */).doSomething(any())
}

// fails :(
@Test
fun `multiple api calls, one after the other`() {
  given(myApi.doSomething(any())).willReturn(Single.just(RESPONSE).delay(2, SECONDS))
      .willReturn(Single.just(OTHER_RESPONSE).delay(2, SECONDS))

  val test1 = repository.doSomething().test()

  test1.await(3, SECONDS)
  test1.assertNoErrors()
  test1.assertComplete()
  // even tried explicitly disposing here
  test1.dispose()

  val test2 = repository.doSomething().test()
  test2.await(3, SECONDS)
  test2.assertNoErrors()
  test2.assertComplete()

  // fails here
  verify(myApi, times(2)).doSomething(any())
}
```

My understanding is that if all subscriptions have been disposed, `shared` observable will dispose off its source. And when `test2` invokes `doSomething()`, another API call will happen. Second test fails to reflect this.

Another thing, if I wrap the API call in `defer()`, both tests pass:

```
private val observable: Observable<SomeResponse> by lazy {
  Single.defer {
    myApi.doSomething(SomeRequestBody())
  }.toObservable().share()
}
```

Hoping someone can provide an explanation for this.

Comment: I may not be getting this correctly, but isn't it because you're initializing the repository internal observable lazily? It's initialized once and calls the `doSomething` method, but it will never call it again while the instance of the repo remains the same. Wrapping it in `defer`, makes it part of the observable that is executed once you subscribe, but `defer` itself is only invoked once. As you subscribe, no new calls to `defer` are made, but it will run the source again which executes `doSomething` line and the test passes. Is this understandable? Does it work if you remove the lazy part?

Comment: @Fred I think that's exactly it. I also noticed that testing against `MockWebServer` (instead of mocking the API as above) worked even without `Signle.defer/fromCallable`. So, it could be that Rx call adapter may be doing something similar. If its not a bother, could you post this as an answer? Thanks :)

Comment: Sure! Be glad to, I'll just do it a bit later on my laptop :) glad it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the issue is the observable initialization. Here's a more detailed explanation.

The problem lies here:

```
private val observable: Observable<SomeResponse> by lazy {
  myApi.doSomething(SomeRequestBody())
    .toObservable()
    .share()
}
```

The variable `observable` is lazily initialized, which means as long as we use the same instance of the repository, it'll only be initialized once.

Consequentially, in the tests, you have a single instance of the repository and several tests. This means, that for the entire test class, the code inside the `lazy` block is run once. Meaning, `myApi.doSomething(any())` is run once. This causes the failure when you try to verify more than one interaction.

The reason why it works when you wrap it in a `defer` is that `defer` creates an observable that will be executed every time a subscriber subscribes (in your case it's a bit more complex because of the `share` operator, but the idea is the same). Like before, `defer` gets executed lazily and never called again during the test. That is to say, that if one could verify the calls to `defer`, then it'll be the same result. However, now each time the observable should run it'll call `myApi.doSomething(any())` and the test will pass.

As you already figured out, you can fix this by wrapping the call in a `defer`. I think you could also simply remove the lazy initialization. Perhaps, even use dependency injection to initialize the object not lazily in the tests, but keep it lazily initialized in the production application.